# Plotly : Dynamically design Dash Bootstrap layout

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am attempting to dynamically create a grid style layout using dash bootstrap Component Layout:

```
from dash import dash_table, html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

def create_cards(date):

    return dbc.Card(

         dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H4(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), id=f"{date}-title"),
                html.H2(id=f"{date}-rent"),
            ]
         )
    )



dbc.Col(

                html.Div([

                    dbc.Row([
                        dbc.Col([create_cards(i) for i in range(5)]), width=4)
                    ], align='center', no_gutters=True),

                    dbc.Row([
                        dbc.Col([create_cards(i) for i in range(5)], width=4)
                    ], align='center', no_gutters=True),

                    dbc.Row([
                        dbc.Col([create_cards(i) for i in range(5)], width=4)
                    ], align='center', no_gutters=True),

                    dbc.Row([
                        dbc.Col([create_cards(i) for i in range(5)], width=4)
                    ], align='center', no_gutters=True)

                ]),

            width={"size": 7, "order": "last"}),
```

The output from this isn't exactly grid-style. Instead I obtain vertically stacked cards.

[image: card-stacked]

I'd like to design something like:

[image]

For reference,

https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/

https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/card/

Comment: You have defined a column that has 4 rows in it. How is it different to the output?

Comment: @pavel Within each row, I'd like a grids of size 4. That is what I am attempting to do. Grid layout vs vertically stacked cards. My code has issues that I need help with.

Comment: @pavel added an image as example.

Comment: So you need to add a row and 4 columns within the row. Right now you're doing it the other way around. Check the very first example in the layout link you attached.

Comment: @pavel I need to do it dynamically. Need a for loop to create `cols` within each `row`.

Comment: Well, your post doesn't say anything about adding components dynamically. I suggest you describe your question in full in the post.

Comment: @pavel It's in the title. Also, I am using `for loop` for dynamically generate cards.

Comment: I guess it should be something like `dbc.Row([dbc.Col(create_cards(i)) for i in range(5)])` because the way it currently is written is that you're creating a column and pass it a list of 4 cards.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @pavel

```
dbc.Col(

                    html.Div([

                        dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col([create_cards(i)], width=4) for i in range(5)
                        ], align='center', no_gutters=True),

                        dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col([create_cards(i)], width=4) for i in range(5)
                        ], align='center', no_gutters=True),

                        dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col([create_cards(i)], width=4) for i in range(5)
                        ], align='center', no_gutters=True),

                        dbc.Row([
                            dbc.Col([create_cards(i)], width=4) for i in range(5)
                        ], align='center', no_gutters=True)

                    ]),

                width={"size": 7, "order": "last"}),
```